# jQuery Datepicker Dependent

Tags: jquery, html

How would I go about on making my two datepickers dependent? Once you click and choose on the first datepicker it automatically goes to the next datepicker to choose the end date and then closes out.

This is my script:

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#dropoffdate").datepicker({
                showOtherMonths: true,
                selectOtherMonths: true,
                minDate: "Today",
                defaultDate: "Today",
            });
            $("#pickupdate").datepicker({
                showOtherMonths: true,
                selectOtherMonths: true,
                minDate: "Today",
                defaultDate: "Today"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

These are my datepickers:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">Pick Up Date</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" id="pickupdate" class="form-control">
                </div>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">Drop Off Date</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" id="dropoffdate" class="form-control">
                </div>
```

Comment: What you mean.. can you explain more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dropoffdate").datepicker({
      showOtherMonths: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true,
      minDate: "Today",
      defaultDate: "Today",
    })
    $("#pickupdate").datepicker({
      showOtherMonths: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true,
      minDate: "Today",
      defaultDate: "Today",
      onSelect: function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $("#dropoffdate").datepicker('show');
        }, 0)
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
```

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/csjzdbyw/10/

Refer: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-show

It is always better to read the docs properly. Most of the time you'll find the solution in the docs. If not, you will at least get a trick.

**The show method:**

> Open the date picker. If the datepicker is attached to an input, the
>   input must be visible for the datepicker to be shown.

Comment: Thank you guys! I did look at the docs for the show method, but the calender disappeared quickly after. I think your propagation code fixed that part, but it flicks me to the top of the page whenever i select the pick up date. I have to scroll down and then select the drop off date which successfully enables and shows up.

Comment: @ONIS add return false; after your code. it will stop the flickering.

Comment: Should i put it under e.stoppropagation? If so, I did that and the flickering is still there.

Comment: @ONIS Check this http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/csjzdbyw/7/ Just add return false instead of e.stopPropagation.

Comment: @K K is it just me or does the show the calendar for 1 second and disappears again?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onSelect` event for this.

```js
$("#pickupdate").datepicker({
  showOtherMonths: true,
  selectOtherMonths: true,
  minDate: "Today",
  defaultDate: "Today",
  onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
    $("#dropoffdate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#dropoffdate").datepicker('show');
    }, 16);
  }
});

$("#dropoffdate").datepicker({
  showOtherMonths: true,
  selectOtherMonths: true,
  minDate: "Today",
  defaultDate: "Today"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="pickupdate" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" id="dropoffdate" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I am going to incorporate the 'selecteddate' into my code. I like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the second date picker and can enable it on the select or change event of first date picker like this.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#pickupdate").datepicker({
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            minDate: "Today",
            defaultDate: "Today",
            disabled: true,
        });
        $("#dropoffdate").datepicker({
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            minDate: "Today",
            defaultDate: "Today",
            onSelect: function() {
                $("#pickupdate").datepicker('enable');
            }

        }).on("change", function() {
            $("#pickupdate").datepicker('enable');
        });

    });
</script>
```

Thank You

Comment: And there is a [show](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#show) method in datepicker plugin to show it

Comment: @RameshKithsiriHettiArachchi its for bootstrap date picker to show it we are talking about JQuery UI date picker.